# Primitive-recursive even/odd - what does it do exactly?

Tags: java, recursion

I know that this method checks if the integer is even, but how exactly? I understood on examples like *fibonacci* or *factorial* how recursion works but not on this on. I think I don't get it because of the syntax.

```
// Assume n >= 0 
public static boolean even(int n) { 
   return (n<=1) ? (n==0) : !even(n-1); 
}
```

What my problem is: It's a boolean method, why is there no "true" or "false"?
How exactly does it check if it's even? If I would do it in if-statements without recursion I would check it like this:

```
if((n%2) == 0)
return true;
```

Comment: `(n == 0)` and `! even(n-1)` are expressions that each have boolean results. You don't explicitly see a "true" or "false" value. If you think through it, you you'll understand why it works for non-negative values. . It's not a well-written function. It returns false for any value of `n` that is less than or equal to -1. And for non-negative values it's very inefficient. I'm supposing it's used as an exercise in understanding recursion, not as a great example of how to determine whether an integer is even or odd.

Comment: This is one of the _worst_ possible uses of recursion imaginable.  If your teacher does not point this out as part of the next lecture, ask for your money back :-)  Recursion is like a chainsaw.  It is an extremely powerful tool, and is indispensable for a specific type of problem, but applying it where it doesn't belong is inexcusable.  One of my pet peeves is professors who teach it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a *JAVA short if else*:

```
condition ? trueCase: elseCase;
```

it equals to below syntax:

```
if(condition){
   trueCase;
}
else{
  elseCase;
}
```

In your code:

```
return (n<=1) ? (n==0) : !even(n-1);
```

equals to:

```
if(n<=1)){
   if(n==0){
     return true;
   }
   else{
     return false;
   }
}
else{
  if(even(n-1)){
    return false;
  }
  else{
   return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this was very enlightening.
Now I understood how to think through.

Answer (score 0):

The statements

```
if((n%2) == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

is equivalent to

```
return (n%2) == 0;
```

any expression that evaluates to a boolean value can be used instead of directly using one of the two boolean values.

As for the function named "even", it basically says an integer is even if the previous integer is not even, unless it is smaller than one, in which case it is even if it is zero.  Since it evaluates to a boolean value, so you can return it as the return value.

You should note that your function does not work for negative values.